# push changes from pip installed git repo

Tags: python, git, pip, conda

I have a conda environment on a new machine, and a github repo set up which is pip installable. It looks something like this

```
library_distro
  |
  |->_pycache_
  |
  |->library_name
  |   |
  |   |->modules and stuff...
  |
  |->.giignore
  |
  |->__init__.py
  |
  |->requirements.txt
  |
  |->setup.py
```

my question is, is there a way to set up a distribution so that it's pip installable, and also if I make modifications to the pip installed library I can push those changes? Right now I have a clone and a pip install. Every time I want to make a change I modify the clone, push the changes, and reinstall the library via pip. I feel like there has to be a cleaner way.

Comment: if the library is something you're creating then just import it and use it directly. If it's a 3rd party library you really shouldn't have it in your repo and only use pip to manage it.

Comment: It's something I'm creating. I can pip install and import it fine, my question is how to set it up so that I can also push modifications

Comment: My advice: clone + [editable install](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#editable-installs).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

phd was right, editable installs are perfect.

In summary, instead of the usual pip install process, an editable install creates a symbolic link to a specific library somewhere on your machine. If you git clone a distribution which is pip installable, you can easily link it to a python via the following command:

`pip install -e path/to/SomeProject`

naturally, if you modify this command to include the path for pip a specific conda environment, you will have successfully pip installed a cloned repo.

`.../envName/bin/pip install -e path/to/SomeProject`